# Button sizes for my calculator Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I'm new to python and tkinter. I've been watching and studying a few tutorials over the past couple of days and my first project was a calculator.

Got a little confused somewhere down the line. If someone could please tell me how I can make the "0" button fill in the gap between the "." button. Also would like the "+/-" to fit evenly with the rest of the column.

I saw in another question similar to this a guy gave an answer as

```
button1.config( height = WHATEVER, width = WHATEVER2 )
```

Since I have my buttons placed in a grid, can I implement this and how?

```
bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0")
bttn_0["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(0)
bttn_0.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F3AR3DLEGEND is incorrect, you **can** get the desired effect using `grid`. You would need to use the `columnspan` keyword to make a widget span multiple columns, e.g.

```
bttn_0.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5, columnspan = 2)
```

For examples, see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: HAHAHA no lie I was just coming back here to say that I used column span. I was looking around and I saw that I used columnspan earlier on the text box "face palm". But thank you guys a lot, I'm very happy with the layout now.

Answer (score 3):

To get the zero to be next to the ".",  set `columnspan` to 2. You might also want to set the column span of the top entry widget to 4 so that it fits exactly over the four columns of buttons (and set `sticky` as well, to get a perfect alignment).

You can't get the +/- button to fit evenly with the others since it's wider. You can, however, make the others fit the +/- button. If you use `sticky="ew"`, the buttons will all expand in width to fill their columns (ie: they will "stick" to the east and west sides of their cell).

Comment: Every thing lined up fine. "pady = 5, padx =5)" on all buttons and I set the width and height to 1 on all buttons. The +/- button fits in perfectly fine now. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can bind my keys instead of having to point and click on every number. But other than that it's coming along very good. I'll upload a pic.

Answer (score -2):

```
bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0", height = my_height, width = my_width)
```

To fill in the gap, just try a few different values, or calculate it based on the window's width and every other button's (in that row) width.

Comment: Awesome I like that. It worked in resizing the button but it's staying centered in that column. I added a picture as an example.

Comment: @AndrewH You can't change that unless you use a different layout method (such as `.pack()`) or if you change the button size. If you want the 0 button to be centered under the 1 and 2 buttons (which I think you want), you'd have to experiment with using different (parent/child) frames.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: "try a few different values" isn't very scientific, and doesn't really solve the problem, it (might) only mask it.  `grid` is actually the perfect geometry manager for this problem -- using `pack` and nested frames will just make the problem harder and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @BryanOakley I actually meant using `.grid()` and a few frames (not too hard to maintain) but all right. Anyway, I did not know about `columnspan`, so this is a learning experience for me as well :)